# what does pm-suspend-hybrid do?

Tags: power-management

`man`  says

```
   pm-suspend
       During suspend most devices are shutdown, and system state is saved in RAM. The system still requires power in this
       state. Most modern systems require 3 to 5 seconds to enter and leave suspend, and most laptops can stay in suspend mode
       for 1 to 3 days before exhausting their battery.

   pm-hibernate
       During hibernate the system is fully powered off, and system state is saved to disk. The system does not require power,
       and can stay in hibernate mode indefinitely. Most modern systems require 15 to 45 seconds to enter and leave hibernate,
       and entering and leaving hibernate takes longer when you have more memory.

   pm-suspend-hybrid
       Hybrid-suspend is the process where the system does everything it needs to hibernate, but suspends instead of shutting
       down. This means that your computer can wake up quicker than for normal hibernation if you do not run out of power, and
       you can resume even if you run out of power. s2both(8) is an hybrid-suspend implementation.
```

From the description, I still don't understand how the last one is related to and different from the first two. E.g., it can work when running out of power, and then isn't it also saving to the disk, and thus same as the second?

Thanks.

Comment: may [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/220659/256099) help?

Answer (score 2):

Manual says it all, `pm-suspend-hybrid` basically do both: `suspend` and `hibernate`, i.e. saves system state to RAM **and** to disk. `pm-suspend-hybrid` is the same as `pm-hibernate` only if your system will experience power cut, but if power is present all the time when suspended then `pm-suspend-hybrid` is more like `pm-suspend` because system will wake up as fast as in pure `pm-suspend`.

In fact you can forget about first two possibilities and use `pm-suspend-hybrid` all the time. The only drawback is that saving state to both RAM and disk is obviously a little bit slower.

Comment: Thanks. "`pm-suspend-hybrid` is the same as pm-hibernate only if your system will experience power cut". But how does `pm-suspend-hybrid` foresee whether and when I am going to cut the power or the battery is run out? If that happens, isn't it too late to write to disk from RAM?

Comment: @Tim I mean power cut when the system is suspended. After `pm-suspend` you will lose unsaved data and need to reboot, but after `pm-hibernate` or `pm-suspend-hybrid` your data are safe.

Comment: @Tim The approach seems obvious: `pm-suspend-hybrid` first saves the RAM on the disk as `pm-hibernate` would do, but does not switch off the power. Then, it just performs a regular `pm-suspend`. When you press power button (or open the lid of your laptop), it just resumes from a regular `pm-suspend`. If power is cut while computer is in "suspend" mode, then all data in RAM is lost. Computer starts from beginning. However, since there is already `pm-hibernate` data on the disk, the computer resumes as if it is simply "hibernated" without knowing the "suspension" thing. This is what I guess.